# Delphi: Left side cannot be assigned to

Tags: delphi

I am converting some C code into Delphi.  The C code has a read/write fucntion to convert from a 2D (x,y) index into a 1D index.

When I try and do the same thing in Delphi I get a "Left side cannot be assigned to" error.

Here is the simplest code I could create to show the error.  Sorry for the length.  It can be copy/pasted in full into a new form with a single button to show the problem.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

type ClassA=class(TObject)
     private
            type DoubleArray=array of double;
            var _src:DoubleArray;
            _w,_h:integer;
     public
           constructor Create(w,h:integer);
           destructor Destroy; reintroduce;
           function at(x,y:integer):double;
end;

type ClassB=class(TObject)
     private
            type DoubleArray=array of double;
            var _d:ClassA;
            //width and height
            _w,_h:integer;
     public
           constructor Create(w,h:integer);
           destructor Destroy; reintroduce;
           procedure CauseError;
end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor ClassA.Create(w,h:integer);
begin
     _w:=w;
     _h:=h;
     setlength(_src,_w*_h);
end;

destructor ClassA.Destroy;
begin
     setlength(_src,0);
end;

function ClassA.at(x,y:integer):double;
begin
     at:=_src[x+y*_w];
end;

constructor ClassB.create(w,h:integer);
begin
     _w:=w;
     _h:=h;
     _d:=ClassA.create(_w,_h);
end;

destructor ClassB.Destroy;
begin
     _d.free;
end;

procedure ClassB.CauseError;
begin
     _d.at(10,10):=_d.at(10,10)+1;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var CB:ClassB;
begin
     CB:=ClassB.create(100,100);

     CB.free;
end;

end.
```

Can anyone help with what syntax I need to use so the "at" function works?

I haven't done much work with classes so am having trouble here.

The compiler complains at this line

```
_d.at(10,10):=_d.at(10,10)+1;
```

OK, this is the C code.  It has both read and write versions.  How do I get Delphi to do this?

The C functions are as follows

```
     /* Read-only and read-write access to grid cells */
    double at(int x, int y) const {
        return _src[x + y*_w];
    }

    double &at(int x, int y) {
        return _src[x + y*_w];
}
```

Comment: A function works by returning a value, you don't assign a value to a function. That's like writing `Sum(2, 3):=15`, it's not gonna work, it's the function that will determine the sum.

Comment: Additionally you `reintroduce` destructors but don't call them. What you really mean to write is `override`.

Comment: OK, I added the C functions to show how I want the Delphi to work.  Is there any way I can translate that so the compiler is happy and it works as expected?

Comment: You don't show where C code assign to the function.

Comment: The C code using "at" is like my example, _u->at(x, y ) -= scale

Comment: That looks weird, I don't know what it's doing. Someone who know C should probably be able to tell..

Comment: See [the documentation for array properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Properties_%28Delphi%29#Array_Properties)

Comment: Thanks Ken.  That solved the problem.

Comment: In the C++ code, the non-const version of `at()` returns a **reference** to a `double`, that is why the compiler allows the return value to be assigned to. But in the Delphi code, `at()` *does not* return a reference, which is why you get a compiler error trying to assign to the return value. Delphi does NOT support a function returning a reference, only a value or a pointer. So you need to tweak the code a little when translating to Delphi. Either return a pointer and dereference it when assigning a new value, or else create separate getter and setter methods

Comment: To be more explizit than Ken: `at` should be an indexed property. Probably even declared `default`.

Comment: @UliGerhardt: Based on the poster's comment *Thanks Ken. That solved the problem*, I think I was explicit enough. :-)

Comment: Apparently. :-) Somehow I missed the comments after yours.